# Create a glowing sphere with script

Tags: materials, scripting, node-editor

I'm trying to create a glowing object with a script.
This is the code I have so far. It runs but the sphere doesn't light up.
How can I fix this?

````py
import bpy

# turn on bloom
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_EEVEE'
bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_bloom = True

# add material
mat_name = 'EmiMat'
bpy.ops.material.new()
bpy.data.materials[-1].name = mat_name
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes.clear()
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeEmission")
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs["Color"].default_value = (0.151736, 0.0997155, 1, 1)
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs["Strength"].default_value = 5.

# add sphere
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(0,0,0))
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
mat = bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name)
ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob.data.materials[0] = mat
```
````

Comment: Have a look at the material. Do you have a material output?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @Jackdaw. That was the problem. Pardon for such a noob question. Today is my first day working with Blender.

Here is the working code:

```py
import bpy

# turn on bloom
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_EEVEE'
bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_bloom = True

# add material
mat_name = 'EmiMat'
bpy.ops.material.new()
bpy.data.materials[-1].name = mat_name
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes.clear()
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeEmission")
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs["Color"].default_value = (0.151736, 0.0997155, 1, 1)
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs["Strength"].default_value = 5.
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeOutputMaterial")
links = bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.links
links.new(
    bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].outputs[0], 
    bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Material Output"].inputs[0])

# add sphere
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(0,0,0))
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
mat = bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name)
ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob.data.materials[0] = mat
```